# is there a constant $C$ so $p(x,y)>C\cdot(\left |x \right |+\left |y \right |)^n$

Tags: functions, inequality, polynomials

Let $P(x,y)\geq0$ for all $x,y$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ such that $P(x,y)=0$ only for $x=y=0$.

Does there exist a constant $C>0$ such that the following inequality $$p(x,y)>C\cdot(\left |x  \right |+\left |y  \right |)^n$$ holds for all $-1\leq x,y \leq 1$?

I thought maybe to use $|x+y|^n \leq 2^n(|x|^n + |y|^n)$ but it didn't work for me.

would be glad for your help.

Thanks.

Comment: appreciate any help..

Comment: Where do $x, y$ live? $\mathbb R$? $\mathbb C$?

Comment: @Justaskin_ From the context, it's $\mathbb{R}$; complex polynomials in several variables cannot have isolated zeros.

Comment: @Justaskin_ - yes it's $\mathbb{R}$